# HTML <sub> inside select option

Tags: html, select

I am trying to get a simple select field with two options, let's say a<sub>c</sub> and b<sub>c</sub>. Somehow, the sub-fields are ignored inside the option-field. How can I fix it to show "c" as an index? So far I've only tried this in Firefox.

Example:

```
<select>
  <option>a<sub>c</sub></option>
  <option>b<sub>c</sub></option>
</select>
```

Comment: `<select>` and `<option>` are difficult or impossible to style in most Browsers. If you really want style make a custom list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element can only take text as content. You can however, use any unicode character inside it. Unicode has subscript characters built in. You would have to use the [unicode characters for subscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).
You could use it like this:

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="a">Hello</option>
  <option value="a">h&#x2090</option>
</select>
```

Your best bet would probably be to just copy and paste whatever subscript character you need.